# Template argument deduction for aggregate template with array

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, c++20

Consider the following program:

```
template<typename T>
struct A { T t[2]; };

int main()
{
   A a{1}; // only one value provided for 2-element array
   return a.t[0];
}
```

In C++20 mode it compiles fine in `gcc`, but fails in Visual Studio with the error:

```
<source>(6): error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'A'
<source>(6): error C2780: 'A<T> A(void)': expects 0 arguments - 1 provided
<source>(2): note: see declaration of 'A'
<source>(6): error C2784: 'A<T> A(A<T>)': could not deduce template argument for 'A<T>' from 'int'
<source>(2): note: see declaration of 'A'
<source>(6): error C2784: 'A<T> A(A<T>)': could not deduce template argument for 'A<T>' from 'int'
<source>(2): note: see declaration of 'A'
<source>(6): error C2780: 'A<T> A(T,T)': expects 2 arguments - 1 provided
<source>(2): note: see declaration of 'A'
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/6ejfW8G77

Which of the two compilers is right here?

(`Clang` is out of question here since it does not support parenthesized initialization of aggregates yet).

Update: Microsoft admitted the bug and promised the fix soon:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/template-argument-deduction-fails-in-case-of-aggre/1467260

Comment: Same error with gcc 10.3

Comment: Not exactly, gcc 10.3 cannot compile even ```A a{1,2};```, which msvc can

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is right, the code should be accepted, and the type of `a` should be deduced as `A<int>` using class template argument deduction (CTAD) for aggregates.

N4868 (closest to the published C++20 standard) [[over.match.class.deduct]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/over.match.class.deduct#1) says (I've excluded some parts that aren't relevant here):

> When resolving a placeholder for a deduced class type where the
> *template-name* names a primary class template `C`, a set of functions and function templates, called the guides of `C`, is formed
> comprising:
> [...]
> In addition, if `C` is defined and its definition satisfies the
> conditions for an aggregate class with the assumption that any
> dependent base class has no virtual functions and no virtual base
> classes, and the initializer is a non-empty *braced-init-list* or
> parenthesized *expression-list*, and there are no *deduction-guide*s
> for `C`, the set contains an additional function template, called the
> *aggregate deduction candidate*, defined as follows. Let *x<sub>1</sub>*,...,*x<sub>n</sub>* be the elements of the *initializer-list* or *designated-initializer-list* of the *braced-init-list*, or of the *expression-list*. For each *x<sub>i</sub>*, let *e<sub>i</sub>* be the corresponding aggregate element of `C` or of one of its (possibly recursive) subaggregates
> that would be initialized by *x<sub>i</sub>* if
>
> - brace elision is not considered for any aggregate element that has a dependent non-array type or an array type with a value-dependent
>   bound,
>   [...]
>
> If there is no such aggregate element *e<sub>i</sub>* for any *x<sub>i</sub>*, the
> aggregate deduction candidate is not added to the set. The aggregate
> deduction candidate is derived as above from a hypothetical
> constructor `C(T1,...,Tn)`, where
>
> - [...]
> - otherwise, `Ti` is the declared type of *e<sub>i</sub>*,
>
> [...]

Instantiations of `A` are aggregates. There's only *x<sub>1</sub>*, the `1`. The bullet about not considering brace elision doesn't apply, because we have a subaggregate (`T t[2]`) that is an array that has a dependent type but not a value-dependent bound. So brace elision is considered, and the `1` would initialize `t[0]`, which is *e<sub>1</sub>*, and is of type `T`.

So, the aggregate deduction candidate is

```
template<typename T> A<T> F(T)
```

which can be used to deduce `A<int>`.

MSVC fails to generate this template. The error message shows that it incorrectly generates one with two function parameters.

CTAD for aggregates was specified in [P1816](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1816r0.pdf), but the rule that allows this to work appeared in an additional paper,
[P2082](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p2082r1.pdf), that fixed several problems. MSVC [claims to implement both since VS 2019 16.7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160#c-compiler-features), but still rejects the code as of 16.10.3.

As an additional data point, EDG 6.2 in strict C++20 mode accepts the code.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Your code won't work because you're trying to instantiate your template by accessing a nested member that has yet to be defined.

MSVC will not be able to deduce the type for you, so you will need to explicitly instantiate the class.

```
template<typename T>
struct A { T t[2] = {0, 0}; };

int main()
{
   A<int> a; //explicit instantiation 
   return a.t[1];
}
```

Comment: While this may be correct, it's not really what the OP is asking for. They don't want a fix for the code, they want to know if the code they've shown is valid according to the language rules.

Comment: The code they've shown will not work for MSVC because it does not support aggregate initialization. OP would have to explicitly instantiate the template to get this to work with MSVC and clang. Updated my answer.

Comment: Language lawyer tagged questions aim not at solving a problem with code, but at understanding what the standard says.  Direct quotes of the standard text are encouraged.  decoding what the rules of the language are is the goal; what compilers do is secondary.   Simply addressing thenproblem in the code is the wrong approach.  For a non language lawyer question, your answer would be fine.

Comment: This explanation does not look right, because if one replaces ```A a{1};``` with ```A a{1,2};```, then MSVC compiles the program without errors.